# Swift: removeFromSubview happens before animation

Tags: ios, animation, swift, jquery-animate

I have a little setup where I have an MPMoviePlayerController setup as a video background. I'm trying to get it to have a smooth transition when it updates/changes. Here's my current code. BTW, newBackground.view.alpha is initially 0.

```
let oldBackground = currentBackground

self.view.insertSubview(newBackground.view, aboveSubview: oldBackground.view)
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5 as NSTimeInterval, animations: {
    newBackground.view.alpha = 1
    }, completion: {
      finished in
      oldBackground.view.removeFromSuperview()
      println("The subview should be removed now")
  })
```

When this executes, the oldBackground.view is immediately removed before the newBackground starts to fade in. The println, however, happens after the animation is completed. I don't understand why the removeFromSuperview happens immediately, but the println happens when I expect it to. If I remove `oldBackground.view.removeFromSuperview()`, the animation fades in and looks fine (but the view obviously hasn't been removed, it's just sitting behind newBackground).

EDIT: **Bizarrely enough, it seems to work as expected in the simulator. Running on my iPhone 6 Plus gives me the issue every time. I've uninstalled and re-run it from Xcode and the problem persists.**

If anyone has any advice for me, I would be very happy. Thank you.

Comment: This are such long shots, I'm only going to put it in the comment: Is the old video still playing or is it over when it transitions? Are you using the same instance of the movie player controller? Are you fading out or set alpha to 0 for the old one?

Comment: Could this possibly be related to iOS 8.1.2? Testing on two different physical iPhones (6 and 6 Plus on iOS 8.1.2) causes the problem, but it works perfectly on the simulator devices (8.1).

Answer (score 0):

I guess when the `newBackground.view.alpha = 1` is executed during animation it brings the background to visibility and overlays the oldBackground.

Comment: Addendum: In `completion` check the bool whether it's actually at the end. It might be called with false prior to the real finalization.

Comment: Thomas Kilian: Even when I check the bool (and even check to make sure the alpha is where it should be at the end of the animation) it still executes immediately. That println only happens once after the animation is complete, but the removeFromSuperview happens immediately. Did you see the bit about working properly in the simulator?

Comment: It was just a guess. Sorry it did not help. Maybe there are other takers.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the new subview above the old subview, old subview goes to the back. This happens before the animation code starts. Make sure your new subview's alpha is 0 before inserting it. And if you want a fade out animation you should set your oldBackground alpha to 0.

Like this :

```
let oldBackground = currentBackground

newBackground.view.alpha = 0

self.view.insertSubview(newBackground.view, aboveSubview: oldBackground.view)
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5 as NSTimeInterval, animations: {
    newBackground.view.alpha = 1
    oldBackground.view.alpha = 0
    }, completion: {
      finished in
      oldBackground.view.removeFromSuperview()
      println("The subview should be removed now")
  })
```

Comment: I mentioned that "newBackground.view.alpha is initially 0" in the original question. My current setup should be adding a transparent newBackground in front of the oldBackground. The newBackground animates to alpha = 1 (therefore hiding the oldBackground completely, allowing it to disappear cleanly). This works perfectly in the simulator, but flashes black on my iPhone 6 Plus. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try changing the time interval? I'd try different times to see if it affects anything.

Comment: To clarify: "flashes black" in my case means the oldBackground.view is removed before the animation, exposing my black main view.

Comment: H. Serdar: The time interval doesn't seem to make a difference. The view is immediately removed, then the println happens after the animation would be complete.

Comment: I just understood the problem. I thought it was showing the new view directly. I don't have any ideas right now but if I think of anything I'll write again.

Comment: Just an idea : Did you try using "addSubview" instead of insert. Maybe the method is causing the problem and you're inserting it at the top so addSubview would do the same.

Comment: I was doing that originally with the same issues. Using that particular method just allows to more cleanly organize the views how I'd like.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Good luck.